# Linear operator between $l^\infty$ and $l^2$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces

Let $T:\mathcal{l}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})\to\mathcal{l}^2 (\mathbb{R})$ be given by
$$
T\left((x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\right) \colon= \left(\dfrac{1}{2^n} x_{2^n}\right)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}.$$

Find $\overline{\mathrm{Im}(T)}$, the closure of the image of $T$.

Comment: what have you done yourself?

Comment: Also considering the nature of $T$, isn't $T(\ell^\infty)=c_0$?

Comment: @ZelosMalum you're right. The image of $T$ is $c_0$, the space of all the sequences converging to $0$, only if $T$ were a map of $\ell^\infty$ into $\ell^\infty$. You see, here $T$ is a map into $\ell^2$.

Comment: I found that T is a bounded linear operator $||T||=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$, and $\mathrm{Im}(T)=\{\left (\dfrac{a_n}{2^n}\right )_{n\geq 1} : (a_{n})_{n\geq 1}$ is bounded$\}$, but I have no idea if the closure contain something more than the image.

Comment: @Bogdan as $T$ is bounded, it is continuous. So, for any subset $A$ of $\ell^\infty$, we have $$T(\overline{A}) \subset \overline{T(A)}.$$ Right? Does this help?

Comment: Can we say what $\overline{l^{\infty}}$ is?

Comment: The range of $T$ contains all finitely supported sequences (show this!). These are dense in $\ell^2$ (show this!). What does this tell you?

Comment: @PhoemueX what do you mean by "finitely supported sequences"?

Comment: @SaaqibMahmuud: A sequence $(x_n)_{n}$ with $x_n = 0$ for all but finitely many $n \in \Bbb{N}$.

Comment: So, any sequence is good.